# SQL Select Statement using IF statement and applying math to conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case-when

Looking to populate a temporary total value field in the select SQL query but this temporary field is created using math of two values. If a certain condition is met then a certain math should be applied if not then another math will be applied, etc.

Example:

```
SELECT Price, Quantity, Type,
CASE WHEN Type = 'Fixed' THEN ((Price * Quantity)/100)
WHEN Type = 'Option' THEN ((Price * Quantity)*100)
ELSE (Price * Quantity)
END AS Value
FROM Holding..Position
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Looks like he wasn't quoting his strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there...

```
SELECT Price
     , Quantity
     , [Type]
     , CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Fixed' THEN ( (Price * Quantity) * 1.00  /100)
            WHEN [Type] = 'Option' THEN ( (Price * Quantity) * 1.00 * 100)
            ELSE (Price * Quantity) * 1.00
        END AS Value
FROM Holding..Position
```

Times it by `1.00` to make sure you get the decimal places in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine.  If you want to add the column to the table, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table holding..Position
    add Value as (CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Fixed' THEN (Price * Quantity)/100
                       WHEN [Type] = 'Option' THEN (Price * Quantity)*100
                      ELSE (Price * Quantity)
                  END);
```